# Can not import MongoClient

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js, npm

Trying to import the MongoClient into my Vue project and expecting it not to throw an error.

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
```

Error in the browser:

```
> utils.js?071e:543 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at Object.eval (utils.js?071e:543)
at eval (utils.js:913)
at Object..**/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js** (chunk-vendors.js:5077)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (read_preference.js?4638:2)
at Object..**/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/read_preference.js** (chunk-vendors.js:3997)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (shared.js?2650:3)
```

[Error in the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cXlJ.png)

I checked the code here: /node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js and found only one split() operation:

```
...const nodejsMajorVersion = +process.version.split('.')[0].substring(1);
```

Figured that process.version (and even process) is undefined. Setting:

```
const nodejsMajorVersion = 14;
```

Solved the issue, but then I got this one:

```
> defaultable.js?6987:55 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'net'
at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./node_modules/defaultable sync recursive (app.js:1088), <anonymous>:2:10)
at Object.workaround_require (defaultable.js?6987:49)
at require (defaultable.js?6987:77)
at eval (server.js?663d:9)
at defaulter (defaultable.js?6987:83)
at defaultable (defaultable.js?6987:63)
at good (defaultable.js?6987:174)
at Object.eval (server.js?663d:5)
at eval (server.js:242)
at Object../node_modules/hbo-dnsd/server.js (chunk-vendors.js:3106)
```

[Error in the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JGjs.png)

```
node --version          --> v14.17.1
npm mongodb --version   --> 6.14.13
```

Already tried to reinstall node and mongodb. Still the same issues.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "snlh_no_ts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.9",
    "mongodb-client-encryption": "^1.2.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: I am not familiar this much with Vue, but does it run in node.js env? I mean, if you try to add it on client side, you dont have node, just browser.

Comment: Vue is a client side javascript code. Mongodb runs only in backend (nodejs ). They are 2 entirely different things

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-node-js-and-javascript/#:~:text=Javascript%20is%20a%20programming%20language,is%20a%20Javascript%20runtime%20environment.&text=Javascript%20can%20only%20be%20run,be%20run%20outside%20the%20browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it would seem you try to import `mongodb` on client-side (front-end), which runs in browser not in `node.js` environment, which is necessary for `mongodb` to work.

In order to solve your problem you should run a node.js server, which will have your db connected and work via api with your front-end.

Comment: That is a correct answer indeed (i am not the OP or i would mark it as accepted)